# Fastlane Flutter pod install warning ios

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, cocoapods, fastlane

I am use Fastlane for continuous deployment for Flutter.

When I try run Flutter `build` command in Fastlane Fastfile I get Warning:

> ▸ Warning: CocoaPods not installed. Skipping pod install. ▸ CocoaPods
>   is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that
>   responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side. ▸ Without CocoaPods,
>   plugins will not work on iOS or macOS. ▸ For more info, see
>   https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins ▸ To install: ▸ brew install
>   cocoapods ▸ pod setup

But I am not get this error when I run Flutter `build` from bash (not in Fastfile)

This is command I run in Fastfile:

```
  lane :beta do

    sh "cd /folder/folder/exampleapp && flutter clean && flutter build ios --no-codesign"

...
end
```

Anyone know why?

EDIT: This error is non-fatal. The build is submit to app store and Fastlane complete. Is this error a problem? I am use Firebase plugin (core, messaging, firestore) so I have pod in my app. I am think this may cause problem, but I have test app and firebase is still work correct.

Comment: I hope that [this link](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/14618) will be usefull.

Comment: @Kerberos Thanks for reply! This seem same issue. But no official solution?

Comment: @Kerberos I have try solution in you link but it not work. Any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Add `gem "cocoapods"` to your Gemfile and then:

```
bundle install && bundle exec fastlane beta
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Gemfile (located in `/ios/Gemfile`), put `gem "cocoapods"`

Therefore any command related to cocoapods can be accessed from your Fastlane

e.g: `sh("pod install")`